# I have 4 SQL Server tables that all i am using same primary key i need below condition SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables

- `client`
- `clientmanager`
- `Employee`
- `project`

in SQL Server. For all tables, I am using a primary key `clientid` so I like to count list of projects, employee, clients mangers using `clientid`.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .

Comment: somebody pls help me

Comment: share your tables structure,what have you tried and expected output then only anyone can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  client.clientid, client.client_name, count(Employee.Employee) as Employee,count(project.project) as project
    FROM    ((client  INNER JOIN clientmanager ON client.clientid = clientmanager.clientid)
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON client.clientid = Employee.clientid)
                      INNER JOIN project ON client.clientid = project.clientid
```

Comment: My Expected out put    
 client id client name no.of employee  no.of projects 
 1             HCL                 2             5
 2         Mindtree                  3             3 
 3              CTS                  4              4

Comment: CHECK NEW ANSWER